# VHDL reset during execution

Tags: vhdl, reset, fsm

I am developing a Secure Sequence Detector, which is a FSM, by using 3 different processes. It has as input *num_in* (8 bits) that represents the input number and a *first* input (1 bit) that has to be '1' only during the first number, otherwise the FSM goes in a state with fixed output. This condition can happen again if the user insert 3 wrong input sequences. The output is composed by an *unlock* signal (equal to '1' if the sequence is correct) and by a *warning* signal (equal to '1' if the sequence is wrong), and they both have to be updated every 5 clock cycles, since the sequence is composed by 5 numbers, even if one of the input is wrong. The first process is:

```
state_register_p : process(rst, clk)
        begin 
            if rst = '0' then   -- initial state, asynchronous rst
                current_state <= S0;
            elsif (clk'EVENT and clk = '1') then
                if(rst = '0') then
                    current_state <= S0;
                    --errors <= -1;
                else
                    current_state <= next_state;
                    five_cycles <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((to_integer(unsigned(five_cycles)) + 1), five_cycles'length));
                    if to_integer(unsigned(five_cycles)) = 5 then
                        five_cycles <= "001";
                    end if;
                 end if;
            end if;
    end process state_register_p;
```

In this FSM I receive each clock a number on 8 bits and I have to check if it is in the right sequence, if it is not, after 5 cycle from the beginnig I set an error. When the error = 3, the FSM goes in another state in which the *unlock* is fixed at 0 and the *warning* at 1, until a reset is given as input again and the FSM starts from the initial S0 state.
My testbench code is like that:

```
clk_tb <= (not(clk_tb) and end_sim) after T_CLK / 2; 
rst_tb <= '1' after T_RESET;

d_process: process(clk_tb, rst_tb)
    variable t : integer := 0; 
  begin
    if(rst_tb = '0') then
      num_in_tb <= (others => '0');
      first_tb <= '0';
      t := 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
      case(t) is 
        -- correct
        when 1 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
        when 2 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
        when 3 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
        when 4 => num_in_tb <= "01100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --101
        when 5 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

        --invalid because of the num_in (error = 1, but still < 3)
        when 6 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
        when 7 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
        when 8 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
        when 9 => num_in_tb <= "01100100"; first_tb <= '0';  --100
        when 10 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

        --invalid because of the two first (blocking condition) 
        when 11=> num_in_tb <= "00100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --37
        when 12=> num_in_tb <= "00100110"; first_tb <= '1';  --38
        when 13=> num_in_tb <= "00100111"; first_tb <= '1';  --39

        --reset is needed
        when 14=> rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;  --unknown behavior here

        -- correct
        when 15 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
        when 16 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
        when 17 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
        when 18 => num_in_tb <= "01100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --101
        when 19 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

        when 20 => end_sim <= '0';
        when others => null; -- Specifying that nothing happens in the other cases 

      end case;
      t := t + 1;
    end if;
  end process;
```

I would like to insert something like that *when 14=> rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;* to reset my FMS. How can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `rst_tb` driven in multiple locations which is a conflict. Remove it from outside of `d_process`, and remove `rst_tb` from your sensitivity list. Then your if-statement will be:

```
if rising_edge(clk_tb) then ...
```

You can create a `when 0 =>` clause on your `t` variable where you perform resetting:

```
when 0 =>
  num_in_tb <= (others=>'0');
  first_tb <= '0';
  t := 0;
  rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;
```

Then you can have `rst_tb` driven again in your `when 14 =>` clause.

```
...

when 14 =>
  rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;

...
```

You will have to make your `T_RESET` shorter than a `clk_tb` period, or your `state_register_p` process will start missing stimulus from `d_process`.

EDIT:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
library STD;
use STD.textio.all;

entity tb is
end tb;

architecture arch of tb is

constant T_RESET : time := 5 ns;
constant T_CLK   : time := 10 ns;

signal clk_tb    : std_logic := '0';
signal rst_tb    : std_logic := '0';
signal trig_rst  : std_logic := '0';
signal num_in_tb : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal first_tb  : std_logic := '0';
signal end_sim   : std_logic := '1';

begin

--  rst_tb <= '0','1' after T_RESET;
clk_tb <= (not(clk_tb) and end_sim) after T_CLK / 2; 

--d_process: process(clk_tb, rst_tb)
d_process: process(clk_tb)
  variable t : integer := 0; 
begin
--    if(rst_tb = '0') then
--      num_in_tb <= (others => '0');
--      first_tb <= '0';
--      t := 0;
--    elsif(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
  if(rising_edge(clk_tb)) then
    case(t) is 
    when 0 =>
      num_in_tb <= (others=>'0');
      first_tb <= '0';
      rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;
    -- correct
    when 1 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
    when 2 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
    when 3 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
    when 4 => num_in_tb <= "01100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --101
    when 5 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

    --invalid because of the num_in (error = 1, but still < 3)
    when 6 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
    when 7 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
    when 8 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
    when 9 => num_in_tb <= "01100100"; first_tb <= '0';  --100
    when 10 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

    --invalid because of the two first (blocking condition) 
    when 11 => num_in_tb <= "00100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --37
    when 12 => num_in_tb <= "00100110"; first_tb <= '1';  --38
    when 13 => num_in_tb <= "00100111"; first_tb <= '1';  --39

    --reset is needed
    when 14 => rst_tb <= '0', '1' after T_RESET;  --unknown behavior here

    -- correct
    when 15 => num_in_tb <= "00100100"; first_tb <= '1';  --36
    when 16 => num_in_tb <= "00010011"; first_tb <= '0';  --19
    when 17 => num_in_tb <= "00111000"; first_tb <= '0';  --56
    when 18 => num_in_tb <= "01100101"; first_tb <= '0';  --101
    when 19 => num_in_tb <= "01001001"; first_tb <= '0';  --73

    when 20 => end_sim <= '0';
    when others => null; -- Specifying that nothing happens in the other cases 

    end case;
    t := t + 1;
  end if;
end process d_process;

end arch;
```

Comment: I am trying your solution, but I still have rst_tb in X state for a clock cycle, showing a red plot in ModelSim, where the clock period is 10ns, and my T_RESET is 5ns.

Comment: I notice it 'seems' to work at the beginning if I do at t = 0 => rst = 0, at t=1 => rst = 0, and then when I give in input my first number in t = 2 => rst = 1, num_in = ..., but in the simulation plot I have a small red line on the rising edge of the rst from 0 to 1, and it still remain in X state at t = 14

Comment: If you initialize `rst_tb` to `'0'` where it's declared: `signal rst_tb : std_logic := '0';`, then it should not be `'X'`. You could do the same with `first_tb`.

Comment: The problem is that when I do in case 14 rst = '0', '1' after T_RESET, the whole signal up to that istant becomes red, in X state, like it is driven also by other processes

Comment: Which signal are you seeing in X state? I don't see that during simulation with ModelSim. Updated my answer with the code I'm simulating.

Comment: thanks, I solved using your solution. The problem whas that there was  an initialization of the reset signal before the case